# Removing the unmatched quotation mark from the string

Tags: regex

I need a regex which will remove the unmatched quotation mark.I have an regex which will remove all the special characters except those between quotation mark.

`[^\w\s'"](?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)`

this will perform the above mentioned process but allong with this i need to replace the unmatched quotation or apostrope mark.

`Input=hai@@#hello'world@'today'` and output should be like `hai hello 'world@' today` my above regex will work well except removing that odd `apostrope.`

Comment: i dont see your regex working, can you give an example here : http://regex101.com/r/vG0cS4

Comment: That regex was given by you :-p bu it doesnt work as expected when an apostrope comes in i.e the example given by me

Comment: @aelor is there any way to achieve my requirement

Comment: hi manoj, which language are you using for this regex ?

Comment: Im using the above regex in apex ..it doesnt work only when the third apostrope comes in..if there is only two (i.e single quotation) it works...I need to find some solution to remove this unmatched apostrope

Comment: @Vasili Syrakis can u help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, this seems to work for me:

```
"hai@@#hello'world@'today'".match(/\w+|'[^']*'/g).join(" ");
```

Matches either words (consisting of alphanumerics) or anything between apostrophes. It will match the first set between apostrophe 1 and 2, but not between 2 and 3 because 2 was already matched.

Comment: @masho actually i need this to be used in apex.I dont think this will work for me

Comment: @ManojChandran well, the regex should be universal, I was referring to the `match` method. I'm sure you can use it in whatever you are using to, I just didn't know what it is. :P

Comment: is there a way to match only the unmatched apostrope according to example only the 3rd one

Comment: @ManojChandran Not sure what you mean, show me what you want as output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498141/regex-pattern-for-replacing-all-special-characters-with-space-except-those-betwe/22498253?noredirect=1#comment34427814_22498253

Comment: @ManojChandran The regex in my answer works for the input in that question.

Comment: The above link is my original question ,When there is a proper closing and opening apostrope it works fine ,if there is an unmatched ie witot proper closing apostrope my regex doesnt work...So i need to sort out some way to remove that odd apostrope

Comment: To be simple ...I need regex to remove unmatched appostrope

Comment: @ManojChandran can't help you without an example. My regex will ignore unmatched single quotes.

Comment: Instead of removing tht unmatched quotaion ...it will be helpful if your regex matches only tht unmatched quote.Bcs the methods in ur expression doesnt support in Apex.